# How to send a push notification with Rules to specified user by grabbing UID from content field?

Tags: 7, rules, notifications

I want to send a push notification to a single Drupal, which, seems simple given the below screen shot.

[image]

This works great when the user is always the same (I simply type in the UID). However, in my case, the UID is always different. Is it possible for me to grab the UID from a content field (e.g. from Content Type 'Friends', I have a field named `field_target_user`) using a token, and have it populate in my Rules' User Identifier field?

Comment: Are you using the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module? or what are you using for notifications? Also, what is the event that causes the rule to fire?

Comment: @NoSssweat No, I'm simply looking to grab the UID from a field I created in a custom content type.

Comment: Click on the `switch to data selection` button and use the corresponding pattern for your field.

Comment: @NoSssweat Oh, if only it were that easy. Lol. User Identifier doesn't seem to want to let me input a token there - simply a uid number.

Comment: Can you provide the event that causes the rule to fire? Better yet, the rule export?

Comment: If my answer still doesn't help, then please include an export of your rue you currently have (as suggested also by @NoSssweat). Also, please add hyperlinks to the modules you're using (wild guess: something like "[Push Notifications](https://www.drupal.org/project/push_notifications)" maybe?).

Answer (score 0):

Use the button that says ***<kbd>Switch to direct input mode</kbd>***. And verify if you can use any of the tokens shown there as the *identifier* you're looking for.

If no appropriate token is shown, then try to add an appropriate Rules Condition with `Entity has field`, to make the field you need available for further processing in the rule. That's also what is mentioned in the Rules UI when you're adding a "data comparison" condition: somewhere it says "*The data selector helps you drill down into the data available to Rules. To make entity fields appear in the data selector, you may have to use the condition 'entity has field' (or 'content is of type')*". For a video tutorial that illustrates the importance of this `Entity has field` condition, refer to [Data types and data selection](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/data-types-and-data-selection), especially what is shown between about 13:30 and 17:30 in that video.

However, as per your "... content field ... from Content Type 'friends'*" (as in your question), the above may not be sufficient yet (= the appropriate token is still not shown). I.e from the label(s) it sounds that this could well be a multi value field (of type entity reference?). In that case you first need to add a "Rules loop" to iterate of the list of friends, so that inside that loop you can use a token related to the `uid` of the current list item being processed.

The above are just 3 of the typical/possible approaches to get access in a custom rule to some token you're looking for. There are others though, such as:

- using Rules Action to "Fetch entity by ID", or
- getting the [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) module involved,
- etc.

**Note**: In case you're using the [Push Notifications](https://www.drupal.org/project/push_notifications) module, you may want to have a look at its community documentation related to [Rules integration](https://www.drupal.org/node/2720421), especially [this screenprint](https://www.drupal.org/files/push-notification-rule-user-account-single-user-account.png) on that page seems pretty similar to what you're looking for (if you can reference the `node:author` token, it should also be possible to reference some other field of a node).